# Is there a global nanorc?

Tags: nano

I've recently started using `nano` quite a bit for code editing.
I've written custom syntax files, and I can `include` them in my local `~/.nanorc`.

However, I do work across multiple accounts, so I manually have to apply the `include` to each user's `.nanorc`.

Is there a system-wide `nanorc` file I can edit, so the changes take effect for all users?

Comment: Check for /etc/nanorc ?

Comment: If you are using homebrew supplied nano on macOS, or compiled it yourself, try `/usr/local/etc/nanorc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The system-wide `nanorc` file is at `/etc/nanorc`

You can also add a `.nanorc` file to `/etc/skel` so all new users have a local `nanorc` file added to their home folder.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I can't believe I didn't find that before.

Comment: @IBPX Don't forget to accept it if this is the answer you're looking for so others (in future) know it worked! Also see my addition above about the `/etc/skel` directory if you're managing a system with multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone who compiled from source landed here and couldn't find `/etc/nanorc`:

That exact question was asked (and answered) here:

[Can't find GNU nano global config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67840073/5637701)